# My Add and remove Button disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an add and remove button for my fields, and i click the remove button to remove a row it deletes them but when i have no rows and click the remove button it deletes both add and remove button.

What i am trying to do to keep both buttons there when there are no rows to delete and you will not be able to click the remove button when there are no rows to remove.

```
         <div style="width:650px; margin-bottom: 35px;" id="dvMaterials">
                <div id="dvMatsBtn" style="position: absolute; bottom: -35px; right: 50px;">
                    <button style="background-color: orange;" class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="Add1">Add Material</button>
                    <button style="background-color: red; color: white;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="Remove1">Remove Material</button>
                </div>
            </div>






function btnAddOnClickEvents() {
$("#Add1").on("click", function () {
    $("#dvMaterials").append($('#dvMaterialsClone').clone().removeAttr('id').show());
});
$("#Remove1").on("click", function () {
    $("#dvMaterials").children().last().remove();
});}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addEquipRow() {
    $('#dvEquip').append(
        $('#dvEquipClone').clone()
            .removeAttr('id')
            //add a common class to the rows you want to remove
            .addClass('equipRow')
            .show()
    );
}

function removeEquipRow() {
    //only remove the last equipRow
    $('#dvEquip .equipRow').last().remove();
}
```

Using a class that is not on the child with the add/remove buttons will keep the buttons from being removed.

Comment: This worked Perfectly! thank you, ill keep that in mind next time, it was my first time creating a clone.

Comment: So i tried this with another clone i have that is having the same problem, it seems to not to work with that one.

Comment: You could open a new question pertaining to that separate issue.

Comment: Ah, it will not let me since i am new.

Comment: Taplar could you take a look at the EDIT code pasted